# Query for Distinct Column Names in MySql

Tags: mysql

If I have the following tables:

```
[table_1]
id
name
address
zip 

[table_2]
id
power_source
zip
```

I need a query that will return the DISTINCT Column names:

```
id
name
address
power_source
zip
```

The number of tables is many but exact number unknown.  i need the distinct column names for the entire database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information_schema is useful for this kind of information...

```
SELECT DISTINCT `column_name` 
FROM `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE table_schema = "[my schema name]";
```

Comment: I love it when a question is answered so fast!   But I hate it when I can't mark it answered in Stack for 11 more minutes!   Thanks Uueerdo!